# Google Script timed schedule to scan column for value then send webhook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I have a Google Sheet that keeps a list of stocks I'm interested in purchasing. In column M is the value "0" if it doesn't meet my target price, or a value greater than "0" if it does. In Column N is the amount I have invested already today.

What I would like to happen is for a Google Script to scan column M every 15 minutes or so and check if the value in Column M is greater than the value in Column N, AND if it is greater than 0.

If it finds a row that matches both these criteria then it would send a webhook to a URL with parameters based on some of the other columns, attached to the webhook URL like so:

?ticker=(Column C)&Company=(Column A)

Plus a few more columns.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry I should clarify that I'm aware of the different types of Google Project triggers (timed etc) and it's the searching a column and sending the webhook I'm having issues with. Based on the great answer below from @fullfine here is my current code (I'll write below the issues I can't figure out now):

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist"); 
  var m = ss.getRange("M1:M50").getValues()
  var n = ss.getRange("N1:N50").getValues()

  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

    if (m[i] > n[i] && m[i] > 0) {
      sendWebHook(i)
    }
  }
}

function sendWebHook(i) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist"); 
  var a = ss.getRange("A"+i)
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://webhookexample.com?Row=a3')
}
```

So I need to figure out how to replace the "a3" in my webhook with the actual row number. This would be a workaround that I can use to solve my initial problem.

Alternatively, if someone could correct the script to include values from the rest of the row to deliver in the webhook that would be amazing. I'm not great at coding but I think perhaps I would grab the values from each required column on that row, create new variables and then pass them into the webhook?

Another issue is that when the webhook runs currently, the service (integromat) receives it ok but in Google Apps it returns a 400 code.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a time based trigger.  You will need to write the script yourself and if you have specific problem and you provide [mcve] to demonstrate that problem then possibly we might be able to help.  Presently your question falls outside of the scope of this forum because it is too broad of a question.  Please focus you question to a single identifiable question.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, I updated it with code used from the answer below. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Please edit the question with all the necessary details if you want to receive accurate help. However, I can give you a little guidance with what you have explained.

To execute functions at certain interval, there are [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). These call a function of your choice following the criteria you want, for example every 15 minutes. To create one, you must go to the left bar, click on `Triggers -> Add Trigger` and in `Select event source` choose `Time driven`. In this menu also choose the function you want to call.

In this case, I attach a couple of functions for your task. The first one is the one that is called by the trigger. It takes the first five values of column `M` and column `N`, and for each of them performs the desired comparison: that the value of `M` is greater than `N` and greater than zero. If this is the case, it calls the second function, which would be responsible for sending the webhook. It receives the index of the columns `M` and `N` to be able to look for other values in other columns with the same index. For example, if `M3` is greater than `N3` and greater than zero, this function receives a 3 to get the value of `A3`.

### Code

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var m = ss.getRange("M1:M5").getValues()
  var n = ss.getRange("N1:N5").getValues()

  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

    if (m[i] > n[i] && m[i] > 0) {
      sendWebHook(i)
    }
  }
}

function sendWebHook(i) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var a = ss.getRange("A"+i)
}
```

### References:

- [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Comment: Hi @fullfine, thanks for the response. I've updated my answer using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so thanks to @fullfine and a little bit of searching this website I managed to crack it.

To get the correct values from the correct row I had to take the [i] value and add 1.

Here is a description of what each of the selected columns in the spreadsheet does so you can see what it's for in my code:

Column AB - Checks if the stock market is open by looking at the current time. Yes or No.

Column F - The category of stock I have chosen. In this case I only want to run the script to find dividend stocks.

Column R - How much I should invest today. This is based on a set of rules I have and is formula based.

All of the other columns should be self explanatory because of the variable names for the webhook.

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist"); 
  var ab = ss.getRange("ab1:ab100").getValues()
  var m = ss.getRange("M1:M100").getValues()
  var f = ss.getRange("F1:F100").getValues()
  var r = ss.getRange("R1:R100").getValues()

  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

    if (r[i] > 0 && f[i] == 'Current Dividends' && ab[i] == 'Yes') {
      sendWebHook(i)
    }
  }
}

function sendWebHook(i) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist"); 
  var row = (i+1)
  var company = ss.getRange("A"+row).getValues()
  var ticker = ss.getRange("C"+row).getValues()
  var currentPrice = ss.getRange("D"+row).getValues()
  var currency = ss.getRange("G"+row).getValues()
  var percent = ss.getRange("AA"+row).getValues()
  var invest = ss.getRange("M"+row).getValues()
  var invested = ss.getRange("N"+row).getValues()
  var purchasePrice = ss.getRange("P"+row).getValues()
  var status = ss.getRange("U"+row).getValues()
  var purchasePricePercent = ss.getRange("Q"+row).getValues()
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://hook.integromat.com/EXAMPLEWEBHOOK?ticker=' + ticker + '&invest=' + invest + '&invested=' + invested + '&company=' + company + '&currentPrice=' + currentPrice + '&currency=' + currency + '&percent=' + percent + '&purchasePrice=' + purchasePrice + '&purchasePricePercent=' + purchasePricePercent + '&status=' + status)
}
```

And now I receive a Facebook message when a stock price is within my buy zone.